# Building against 3.x SDK in Xcode 3.2.3 for iPhone only app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

Is it possible? Because if I build against SDK 4.0, my app goes wacko, doing silly things and generally not working properly. If I build against 3.2 however, it works splendidly, but I get a warning saying:

> [BWARN]warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'.

My app was originally (and still is) a 2.2.1 app, but as I'm updating it, I need to compile it with the new Xcode for it to get approved.

Is there really no way to build an iPhone-only app against 3.x sdk? Not too happy investigating behavior like this, if it works so well with sdk 3.2. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All new and updated iPhone apps need to be built against the 4.0 SDK. iOS 3.2 is iPad-only.

From [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/archives/2010/june/):

> Make sure that your applications are
>   compatible with iOS 4. All new
>   applications and updates to existing
>   applications must be built with iPhone
>   SDK 4. In addition, the App Store will
>   no longer support applications that
>   target iOS 2.x.

Not what you wanted to hear, I know. I wanted to submit a small patch to my app but had to update for iOS4 first too.

Answer (score 1):

Building for 3.2 means building for iPad right now. You're getting an error because you're trying to build an iPhone app which has a config for "iPhone Only" set on an SDK version for the iPad.

Answer: Don't change the "Base SDK" config to 3.2 - leave it at 4.0. Change the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" back to 3.1.3.

**Edit:** I suppose this doesn't fix your "wacko" behavior on building for 4.0, but your only other choice is downgrading to the last version of xCode.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing too since my app doesn't take advantage of any iOS 4 features. I see no reason why my app couldn't run against OS 3. Anyway, I compiled it against iOS 4 and submitted my update to the App Store.

Too bad all the OS 3 users that aren't going to upgrade to iOS 4 get left out in the cold as far as updates go.

Comment: Building your application for iOS 4 does not prevent it from running on earlier versions.  This is what the Deployment Target build setting is for.